# how to get value from xml file and use it programmaticaly in android studio

Tags: android, xml

i am working on a project in android studio , my app contain lot of Text_Views and according to the user choses my app will show those Text_Views , sometimes it need to show the whole of them at once and in other times it show only some of them

in case of showing the whole Text_Views my app should decrease the Text_Views size and in the case it should increase their size 
so
 my aim is to get the dimens values that are already set in the XML file to use them in java code programmaticly 
the only thing left to do is to select the appropriate size to each chose according to what the user selects

i tried with that to get the value from the XML file  :

```
int val = R.dimens.<name of the size>
```

but it give me a totaly different value from the value that assigned in the XML file

the text code in xml file

```
 <dimen name="text_size">12sp</dimen>
```

.

```
int val = R.dimens.text_size;
```

i expected that this will give me the same value that is set in the xml file but it didnt , it gave me random number that is sooo far from what i wrote in the xml file

hope you can help me that

greeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
int valueInPixels = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimens.text_size)
```

But, note, that you will get value according to your phone dencity, to get original value divide it with DisplayMetrics density:

```
int dp = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimens.text_size) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)
```

Comment: HOOOOOOOOOO !!!! how can i thank you , i was searching for that and trying many method to solve this for a day without getting a good result 
thanks soo much that solved my problem